# How To Handle Table Column Named With Reserved Sql Keyword?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has a column named `RANK` which is a keyword in Oracle.

Now I need to insert data in this table :

```
insert into mytbl (RANK)
select RANK from other_table
```

when executing this query I got the following error :

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

How does one escape a keyword?

Comment: @Madhivanan - RANK was introduced into the Oracle lexicon relatively recently.  It's oftem not possible to change the data models of legacy systems.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Oracle uses double quotes `"` to escape reserved words.

```
insert into mytbl ("RANK")
select "RANK" 
from other_table
```

One other note, Oracle requires correct case as well.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, You shall not use reserved keywords as column name and table name.

Oracle uses Double quotes `"` to parse reserved keywords so you can parse the keywords
by placing it in doubles quotes `""`.

```
insert into mytbl ("RANK")
select "RANK" 
from other_table
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there is , in my query.

```
UPDATE SCHEMA.TABLE SET PART_NO = '1S7F530400', WHERE PART_NO = '1S7?F5304?00';
```

This should be:

```
UPDATE SCHEMA.TABLE SET PART_NO = '1S7F530400' WHERE PART_NO = '1S7?F5304?00';
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been mentioned before, but to emphasize, one must *exactly* match the case *in all uses*. When I needed to extract the `GROUP` column and order it, "Group" did not work. It had to be "GROUP" in both cases such as

```
select "GROUP" from PICKLIST
order by "GROUP"
```