# trigger fails in Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers

EDIT: Per request here is what's happening in SQL*Plus
EDIT 2: The issue was the column name being a keyword
    SQL> drop table comments;

```
Table Dropped.

SQL> create table comments (
 2 comment_id number not null,
 3 post_id number not null,
 4 user_id number not null,
 5 message varchar2(2500) not null,
 6 timestamp timestamp(6) not null);

Table Created

SQL> create sequence comment_seq
 2 start with 1
 3 increment by 1
 4 nomaxvalue;

Sequence Created

SQL> ed

Wrote file afiedt.buf //NOTEPAD OPENED UP

1 create or replace trigger comment_trigger
2      before insert on comments
3      for each row
4 begin
5     select comment_seq.nextval
6     into :new.comment_id
7     from dual;
8 end;
SQL> /

    ERROR at Line 2:
    ORA-06552: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
    ORA-06553: PLS-320: the declaration of the type of this expression is
    incomplete or malformed

    SQL> show errors
    No errors.
```

Comment: `number(300)` isn't a valid data type.

Comment: my bad on the fat fingering of 30 and 300.  I had to manually input this from another machine that doesn't have internet access.

I've re-read the rest of the code & it matches

Comment: Which version are you on? I suspect it doesn't like you having a column called `timestamp`, since it's a reservd word; but since it works for Justin, I'm wondering if this ia a version (or patch level) issue?

Comment: @Alex - THANK YOU! IT was the Version(Patch) issue.  I'm on Oracle 10g and it didn't seem to like it being called timestamp.  I renamed the column and it's ALL GOOD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I correct the data types of the numeric columns (`number(300)` is not a valid data type), that code seems to work for me.  If you're getting an error, that implies that you are doing something other than what you've posted here.

```
SQL> create table comments (
  2    comment_id number not null,
  3    post_id    number not null,
  4    user_id    number not null,
  5    message    varchar2(2500) not null,
  6    timestamp  timestamp(6) not null
  7  );

Table created.

SQL> create sequence comment_seq
  2  start with 1
  3  increment by 1
  4  nomaxvalue;

Sequence created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace trigger comment_trigger
  2    before insert on comments
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    select comment_seq.nextval
  6      into :new.comment_id
  7      from dual;
  8* end;
SQL> /

Trigger created.
```

Comment: I dropped the sequence and the table.  Recreated them as you wrote.

Then I typed ed like you did.  Notepad popped up and I replaced it with the following:

create or replace trigger comment_trigger
before insert on comments
for each row
begin
select comment_seq.nextval
into :new.comment_id
from dual;
end;

Then I saved the file - closed note pad and pressed '/' and hit enter

Same error as before

Is there an error log that would tell me exactly it doesn't like

Comment: @PSU_Kardi - In SQL*Plus, you can type `show errors` to get the syntax errors.  Can you cut & paste from a SQL*Plus session just like I did that shows you creating the table, creating the sequence, creating the trigger, getting the error, and then typing `show errors`?  Then edit your question to include that copy & paste.

Answer (score 1):

*Expanding on comment...*

The error is caused by the column named `timestamp` in the `comments` table. Using a reserved word as an object name is not a good idea as it can lead to confusion and obscure problems, and can need to be escaped (as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11629966/266304)).

In this case, even though the table was created without error, the trigger (though it could be any compiled PL/SQL 'library unit') fails, specifically because the column name is a *datatype* rather than just a reserved word.

This seems to be bug 6331062, 'PLS-320 if a column name is a datatype (eg "TIMESTAMP")', which the bug report says has been fixed in patchsets 10.2.0.5 (see note 1088172.1) and 11.1.0.7, and in the 11gR2 base release - which would explain why Justin and Craig didn't see it. (I assume Justin is on 11gR2; Craig's output shows he's on 11.1.0.7).

Answer (score 0):

What version of Oracle?

Also, what happens if you just put the trigger code straight into SQL*Plus instead of using "ed"?

But strange, because your script works just fine for me:

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0

SQL> create table comments (
  2   comment_id number not null,
  3   post_id number not null,
  4   user_id number not null,
  5   message varchar2(2500) not null,
  6   timestamp timestamp(6) not null);

Table created.

SQL> create sequence comment_seq
  2   start with 1
  3   increment by 1
  4   nomaxvalue;

Sequence created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace trigger comment_trigger
  2        before insert on comments
  3        for each row
  4   begin
  5       select comment_seq.nextval
  6       into :new.comment_id
  7       from dual;
  8*  end;
SQL> /

Trigger created.
```