# How to select the column names of a table where column data contains '%' in the values?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, sql-like

How to select the column names of a table where column data contains '%'  in the values?

Eg: In the table COMP there are two columns(Addr, Comp_Name) which has data containing '%' in its string. So my query should return those column_names(Addr, Comp_Name)

Comment: Put double quotes around it. `SELECT "my_poorly_named_field_%" FROM mytable;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Handle Table Column Named With Reserved Sql Keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629966/how-to-handle-table-column-named-with-reserved-sql-keyword)

Answer (score 1):

I dont get you right but i thing this will help you

You can use the escape identifier

```
--Queries

-- for %
select * from test_a where col1 like '%\%%' escape '\';

--for _ 
select * from test_a where col1 like '%\_%' escape '\';
```

Comment: Hi Aljassi,
I want to select the column of a table whose data has '%'

Comment: hi, i dont know if it s possible with a simple select BUT you can make a function  and solve that.

Comment: 1. get all column name of the table
--SELECT  column_name FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE' AND data_type = 'VARCHAR2' order by 1;
2. with a cursor for each column name, count number of data set  and save column name when count > 0
-- v_sql := ' select count(1) from test_a where '||column_name||' like ''%\%%'' escape ''\'' ';  execute v_sql into a variable
-- variable > 0 then save column name