# How to resolve ColdFusion analyzer error while upgrading?

Tags: coldfusion

I am upgrading my ColdFusion from 2018 to 2021. While running my code against the analyzer I got below error.

[image]

For below code

```
<Cfquery name="getcheck" datasource="***">
Select userid,function as funct from users where 
','||UPPER(function)||',' like '%,#UCase(Function)#,%'
</Cfquery>
```

This code works correctly on SQL

Screenshot of actual code

[image]

Comment: Which SQL server are you on? You need to do concat operations, not try to print values. https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_concat.asp

Comment: Looks like an Oracle dsn. Just for grins, what happens if you temporarily change the column name to "functionX"? Obviously the query can't execute, but maybe it is a false positive from the analyzer.. .

Comment: I am using oracle not sql

Comment: (...By false positive I mean maybe it is getting tripped up by the keyword "function"? Worth a try to see if it works when that name is temporarily changed to something else.)

Comment: Didnt worked. Tried

Comment: Was this working with CF 2018 and it's NOT working with CF 2021? Or is this new code you're running on CF 2021 and you just happen to also be upgrading from CF 2018?

Comment: Good question. Looking closer, that's a basic compilation error, not a Code Analyzer issue. If you attempt to execute that query in CF2018, it throws the same exception. It's caused by the use of the keyword "function".  Changing the name to a non-reserved word like "functionX" resolves the error.

Comment: I have to use that word as i am having column with same name in my db table. How to use reserved keyword as variable in coldfusion?

Comment: Technically, there's no requirement that a CF variable name be the same as the db column it's compared to. It's perfectly valid to write `WHERE ColumnName = '#ChickenNoodleSoup#'`. So renaming the CF variable is feasible. Whether you are able to rename the db column depends on restrictions in your shop, like dba approval, etc..

Answer (score 2):

(Too long for a comment ....)

> ```
> Invalid CFML construct found on line 108 at column 131.
> ColdFusion was looking at the following text:
>
> )
>
> The CFML compiler was processing:
>
>     An expression beginning with UCase, on line 108, column 117.This message is usually caused by a problem in the expressions structure.
>     The body of a Cfquery tag beginning on line 107, column 25
>     ....
> ```

Looking closer, that's a basic *compilation* error, not a Code Analyzer issue. It appears the use of the keyword `function` in that context is causing the CF compiler to choke. Change the name to a non-reserved word like `functionFoo` and the error disappears.

Since `Function` is a reserved word in most every database, and language, I'd **strongly recommend changing the column and variable name**, as it'll just continue to cause unexpected issues and errors like this in the future. If you absolutely cannot rename the database column, start by escaping it in the sql query. For Oracle try [enclosing the column name in double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11630008)

You may also need to change the CF variable name and/or prefix it with the appropriate scope name: such as `#form.Function#` or `#variables.function#` instead of just `#function#`. Though again, to avoid conflicts, it's far better to just change the variable name.  The CF parameter should also be wrapped in cfqueryparam for db performance and sql injection protection.

```
   <cfquery name="getCheck" datasource="***">
      SELECT userid, "function" as funct 
      FROM   users 
      WHERE  ','||UPPER("function")||',' LIKE
           <cfqueryparam value="%,#UCase(FORM.Function)#,%"
               cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">

   </Cfquery>
```