# I am getting this error while executing update query in python code

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

**code:-**

```
upd=(f"update order_tb set ('name=:{self.name.get()}','contact=:{self.contact.get()}','address=:{self.address.get()}','store=:{self.combo_store.get()}','groceries=:{self.groceries.get()}','{O_ID}',where o_id=:O_ID")
cur.execute(upd)
```

****error:-****

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
```

Comment: You should modify the question title to reflect the question being asked. "I am getting x error" doesn't ask a question or  give any information about the error in question. This will help the relevant people find the question. Something like "ORA-01747 in Oracle when trying to execute update query in python code."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459204/ora-01747-invalid-user-table-column-table-column-or-column-specification)

Comment: try to print upd before cur.execute(upd) and check if the syntax of the statement is ok, I mean name of table, columns, ... and if there's any superfluous character.

Answer (score 1):

With your `f`string you are sending to Oracle someting like this statement (simplified)

```
update order_tb set ('name=:X1','contact=:X2','address=:X3','store=:X4','groceries=:X5','o_id',where o_id=:O_ID
```

Which indeed leads to `SQL Error: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification`  as you completely violates the valid `UPDATE` syntax.

what you probably intend is similar to following statement (not sure what you intend with the part  `'{O_ID}'` )

```
update order_tb set  name=:X1, contact=:X2, address=:X3, 
                     store=:X4, groceries=:X5 
where o_id=:O_ID
```

So the generall advice is *print the `UPDATE` statement before you execute it and check the syntax*